# Show that the action of $PSL_2(\mathbb{R})$ on $\mathbb{H}$ is transitive

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, solution-verification, modular-forms

Show that the action of $PSL_2(\mathbb{R})$ on $\mathbb{H}$ is transitive , i.e for all $z,w \in \mathbb{H}$ there exists some $g \in  PSL_2(\mathbb{R}) $ such that $gz=w$ .

It suffices to find a $g \in PSL_2(\mathbb{R})$ with $$gz=i \ \ (1)$$ for any z $ \in \mathbb{H}$ . For $w \in \mathbb{H}$ there is also a $ h \in PSL_2(\mathbb{R}) $ such that $$hw=i $$. Thus we have $$(h^{-1}g) z=w $$

(1) is equivalent to $$ g^{-1}i=z \iff \frac{ai+b}{ci+d}=z \iff \frac{ac+bd}{c^2+d^2}+\frac{i}{c^2+d^2}=x+iy $$

Choosing $c=0 $ leads to $$ \frac{1}{d^2}=y $$

Thus we find $d=\pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{y}}$
and $a=\pm \sqrt{y}$ and $b=\pm \frac{x}{\sqrt{y}}$ .

I think if you find  this g then you can calculate $h^{-1}g$ .

Thanks for help .

Comment: Looks fine. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2529664/how-to-show-the-action-of-sl-2-mathbb-r-on-the-complex-upper-half-plane-is-t?noredirect=1&lq=1).